# Код выдаёт ошибку в примере из документации tensorflow: OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

Недавно я решил сделать нейросеть на python для работы со структурированными данными. Нашёл подходящий пример на сайте tensorflow https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/feature_columns. В Google collab он работает, но у меня выдаёт ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


  File "D:\Scripts\For Dyadya Seva\MyCode.py", line 62, in <module>
demo(feature_column.indicator_column(crossed_feature))
  File "D:\Scripts\For Dyadya Seva\MyCode.py", line 44, in demo
print(feature_layer(example_batch).numpy())
  File "C:\Users\ivche\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 968, in __call__
outputs = self.call(cast_inputs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ivche\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\feature_column\dense_features.py", line 144, in call
tensor = column.get_dense_tensor(transformation_cache,
  File "C:\Users\ivche\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\feature_column\feature_column_v2.py", line 4466, in get_dense_tensor
return transformation_cache.get(self, state_manager)
  File "C:\Users\ivche\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\feature_column\feature_column_v2.py", line 2679, in get
transformed = column.transform_feature(self, state_manager)
  File "C:\Users\ivche\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\feature_column\feature_column_v2.py", line 4402, in transform_feature
id_weight_pair = self.categorical_column.get_sparse_tensors(
  File "C:\Users\ivche\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\feature_column\feature_column_v2.py", line 4260, in get_sparse_tensors
transformation_cache.get(self, state_manager), None)
  File "C:\Users\ivche\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\feature_column\feature_column_v2.py", line 2679, in get
transformed = column.transform_feature(self, state_manager)
  File "C:\Users\ivche\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\feature_column\feature_column_v2.py", line 4218, in transform_feature
return sparse_ops.sparse_cross_hashed(
  File "C:\Users\ivche\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\sparse_ops.py", line 595, in sparse_cross_hashed
return _sparse_cross_internal(
  File "C:\Users\ivche\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\sparse_ops.py", line 643, in _sparse_cross_internal
indices_out, values_out, shape_out = gen_sparse_ops.sparse_cross(
  File "C:\Users\ivche\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_sparse_ops.py", line 1054, in sparse_cross
return sparse_cross_eager_fallback(
  File "C:\Users\ivche\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_sparse_ops.py", line 1137, in sparse_cross_eager_fallback
_result = _execute.execute(b"SparseCross", 3, inputs=_inputs_flat,
  File "C:\Users\ivche\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py", line 59, in quick_execute
tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

Пробовал найти решение этой проблемы, но ничего не помогло. Кто может подсказать, что делать?
Операционная система: windows 10 64 bit
Версия tensorflow: 2.2.0

Answer (score 1):

Вот ответ на ваш вопрос: [Python int too large to convert to C long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38314118/overflowerror-python-int-too-large-to-convert-to-c-long-on-windows-but-not-ma)

В Python 2 "int" в Python было эквивалентно C long. В Python 3 «int» - это произвольный тип точности, но numpy по-прежнему использует «int» для представления типа C «long» при создании массивов.

Размер C long зависит от платформы. В Windows он всегда 32-битный. В unix-подобных системах он обычно 32-битный в 32-битных системах и 64-битный в 64-битных системах.

Google collab крутится на Unix 64-bit. Попробуйте использовать `dtype=np.int64`